# Как при выводе чисел из списка умножать их на определенный символ?

Tags: python, список

```
arr = [3,4,5,6,10]
print('\n'.join(map(str, arr))*"*")
```

нужно реализовать такой вывод при чем без цикла `for()`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я попытался повставлять `* "*"` в разные части `print()` , но ничего толком не происходит а просто вылезает ошибка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно так:

```
print(*map(lambda n:"*" * n, arr), sep = "\n")
```

либо так:

```
print(*map("*".__mul__, arr), sep = "\n")
```

место `sep="\n"` модно использовать `join`

```
print("\n".join(map(lambda n:"*" * n, arr))) 
print("\n".join(map("*".__mul__, arr)))
```